# Passar informações para o usuário através de cookies

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

eai, bom queria saber como faço pra passar informações para o usuário através do cookie (quando ele estiver logado aparece botão de perfil, se ele for admin aparece botão de criar produto, etc etc) obrigado
Eu pesquisei algumas coisas na internet, porem os artigos e vídeos que achei não consegui entender bem.

Comment: Não recomendaria fazer isso controlando por cookies. Para identificar o usuário, se está logado e se é administrador você já deve ter utilizado sessões; use-as da mesma forma para decidir que conteúdo entregará ao usuário. É basicamente um `if` em PHP que define o HTML.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica